# Cоздаю сайт кинотеатра на js

Tags: javascript, массивы, циклы

> Не могу понять, как сделать так, чтобы нормально определяло ряд и номер места при клике на кнопку. Буду благодарен за помощь

```
let cinemaHall = document.querySelector('.cinemaHall');

for(let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
        cinemaHall.innerHTML += `
            <p class="seats" data-color="greenColor"></p>
        `;
    }
}

let seats = document.querySelectorAll('.seats');

for(let i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
    let seatsAtr = seats[i].getAttribute('data-color');
    seats[i].onclick = function() {
        if(seatsAtr == "greenColor") {
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
            seatsAtr = "redColor";
            seats[i].textContent = i+1;

        } else {
            this.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
            seatsAtr = "greenColor";
            seats[i].textContent = '';
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `<p class="seats" data-color="greenColor" data-row="${j}" data-seat="${i}"></p>`

Comment: @vp_arth `j` <-> `i` ?

Comment: @Igor, 5 рядов по 30 мест более правдоподобно, чем 30 рядов по 5 =)